# KDB+ How to Check that All Columns Have the Same Sign?

Tags: dataframe, match, kdb

I have a table with the following columns: date, name, cashType, t1, t2, t3. I want to add a column that returns a boolean if the t1, t2, and t3 columns are equal.

This works but I had to hardcode t1, t2 and t3. The columns names change depending on the date. I want to pass in a list of columns `dateCols:-3#cols data` into the below code.

```
update validateSign: {x=/} each flip signum (d2018_05_28; d2018_05_29; d2018_05_30) from data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this instance we can use `data dateCols` to call the column list within the query,

```
update validateSign:{x=/}each flip signum data dateCols from data
```

However, I do not think this query will generate the desired results, an alternative would be

```
update validateSign:1=(count distinct@)each flip signum data dateCols from data
```

Comment: This method of indexing the data table within a select on the data table is not good practice.

Answer (score 4):

For an update statement containing variable column names, you’ll need to use a *functional* update. The below links contain more information:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/
http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals/queries_q_sql#Functional_Forms_of_select_and_update

Usually the easiest way to deduce the arguments of your functional update is to use the `parse` function on an example like you’ve provided.

Answer (score 1):

Georges comment about the original solution giving wrong results is correct since `{x=/}` does not tell you that all items in a list are equal, it is a rolling boolean that checks if the next item matches a zero or one. Something like `{all x[0]=x}` would achieve what you wanted.

To Jemmas point, if your column names can vary and you want to use a select construct then you would have to use a functional select of the form:

```
q)data:([] date:10#.z.D;name:10?`4;cashType:10?`A`B;t1:-5+10?10;t2:-5+10?10;t3:-5+10?10)
q)dateCols:-3#cols data
q)![data;();0b;(1#`validateSign)!enlist ({all flip x[;0]=x};(flip signum@;enlist,dateCols))]
date       name cashType t1 t2 t3 validateSign
----------------------------------------------
2018.05.31 hjkn B        -1 4  0  0
2018.05.31 okdm A        2  0  3  0
2018.05.31 jggp A        3  -3 0  0
2018.05.31 oimo A        -1 -2 -3 1
2018.05.31 naea A        -1 4  3  0
2018.05.31 jadb B        1  0  1  0
2018.05.31 nojg A        4  4  4  1
2018.05.31 keno B        4  2  -5 0
2018.05.31 hdai B        -3 1  -5 0
2018.05.31 mfmf A        0  1  -5 0
```